# Whats the cause, Swift is supposed to be that much faster than Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, performance, swift

As Craig revealed within the announcement of Swift, it is said to be faster than Objective-C by far.

But i'm not that convinced by that comparison because a properly implemented algorithm should be fastest in C, because it can be highly optimized by the compiler and is hardware-friendly by nature. 
So I would guess the best performance Swift could get, would be the performance of the same algorithm in C.

And as C is part of Objective-C, why is there a that big gap between Objective-C and Swift performance?

The only reason I could imagine is Apple using NSNumbers and such instead of C types, but should not be the base for a Obj-C - Swift comparison, right?

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/242816/how-can-swift-be-so-much-faster-than-objective-c

Comment: Just a warning, questions similar to this have been asked a few times and downvoted heavily. There is a pretty good discussion here though: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/242816/how-can-swift-be-so-much-faster-than-objective-c

Comment: You really should get the free Swift book that Apple now offers on the iStore.  Finding experts on Stack Overflow for a language that is two days old seems... overly optimistic.  On another note, I do find Apple's "Objective C sux, try Swift" position quite amusing.

Comment: yeah, that book is on my to-do ;) i was just wondering, if Swift could really fully replace Objective-C as it looks like a mix of various scripting languages, like JS and such, to me. But I like that it seems to be really fast!

Comment: They are most certainly using Objective-C `NS*` types for the performance comparisons, if there is a comparison that primarily number crunching. Perhaps that's not fair, but it's a marketing talk and the widespread use of `NS*` types *somewhat* justifies it.

Comment: Overzealous zappers strike again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is largely speculation (although informed speculation) but my two big theories are:

1) <strike>No</strike> Reduced dynamic method dispatch. Every method call in Objective-C goes through `objc_msgSend`. In the fastest case, this can be as quick as 16 instructions, but it can also be a lot slower. Swift will incur this penalty in fewer situations than Objective-C will, for instance: method calls to swift-only protocol methods do not hit `objc_msgSend`, but if the protocol is declared in Obj-C, or if the swift protocol is decorated with `@objc` (such that it can be adopted by Objective-C objects as well), then method calls to methods in that protocol adopted by swift objects appear to be dispatched via `objc_msgSend`.

2) Avoiding heap allocations. In Objective-C, (effectively) every object is heap allocated. With a static type system, the compiler can infer more about the lifecycle of an object and allocate it on the stack unless it has to cross the Objective-C boundary (or is too big to be allocated on the stack).

I suspect that #2 is the much bigger of these two, but both are likely significant contributors. I'm sure there's more to it than just this, but these are two very likely contributors.

Comment: I'm not sure (1) is as absolute as you make it sound. Admittedly it looks they've set things up so that dispatch is _usually_ static but e.g. protocols carry over as an orthogonal feature to subclasses — I don't see how they could do that, especially while claiming to be using the runtime, without dispatching those calls dynamically. At this stage I could just be suffering a failure of comprehension, of course. (Also my reading was that objects continue to live on the heap but the new concept of `struct`s, which are like C#'s rather than C's, introduce generic stack objects)

Comment: Method calls to swift-only protocols do not hit `objc_msgSend`. If the protocol is declared in ObjC or if the swift protocol is decorated with @objc, then method calls to protocol methods are dispatched via `objc_msgSend` so you're right that it's not as simple as "No dynamic method dispatch" but there are significant opportunities for big reductions in dynamic dispatch... editing.

Comment: You've obviously read a lot further ahead than I've had time to. Thanks for setting me straight. +1, etc.