# Protocol required methods in swift are dynamic then how swift is to be said faster than objective c?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have read so many articles like [Whats the cause, Swift is supposed to be that much faster than Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019229/whats-the-cause-swift-is-supposed-to-be-that-much-faster-than-objective-c)
about Objective-C and Swift performance but didn't get any exact answer that make Swift really fast as compared to Objective-C, As said Objective c is dynamic dispatch then I have seen dynamic dispatch in Swift as well. like in below example.

```
Protocol Person {
    func hasLife()
    func canWalk()
}
```

both function will be dynamic dispatch, Then how can say Swift is faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well Read a little about static dispatch. In Swift these are value types :
Int, Double, String, Array, Dictionary, Set, Struct, Enum, Tuple

And value types use static dispatch because they don’t need inheritance. So in many cases these are static and fast.
In your example if you make protocol extension and methods of that extension would be static dispatch which makes Swift faster and rest you can read in the same example [Whats the cause, Swift is supposed to be that much faster than Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019229/whats-the-cause-swift-is-supposed-to-be-that-much-faster-than-objective-c).

```
extension Person{

    //  Dynamic dispatch coz required method
    func hasLife()
    {
        print("True")
    }

    //  static dispatch coz not required
    func isAlive()
    {
        print("True")
    }
}
```